# Do PSN wallet funds expire?

Tags: psn

I recently applied a $50 PlayStation Network credit to my account, but I only used part of it. How long will this money stay in my account, and does it ever expire? Will I get a notice if they do? Either way, what happens?

Comment: It stays in your wallet, fairly sure that'd be illegal to just wipe your funds

Comment: @Domocus - Of course there will be a clause in their legal jargon that says if Sony goes under, or even just scraps the store, that funds are non-refundable in this case.

Comment: Well, yes, but if it was going under, what would be the point of buying something on the store? :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Sony themselves](http://uk.playstation.com/psn/news/articles/detail/item228732/PlayStation-Network-Cards-FAQ/), your wallet funds do not expire.

A PSN gift card however, does, if not applied to your wallet within a year of purchase.

Comment: I got like 4 reminer emails over the course of two years telling me I had funds in my wallet, too!

Answer (score 0):

Sony will empty your wallet out if you do not buy anything in 3 years. It shows up as a system debt for the full amount with no details of anything. Playstation Customer support over the phone, **1-877-971-7669**, say they turn it over to the state you're registered in due to an unclaimed property law.  They point you towards [www.unclaimed.org](http://www.unclaimed.org) to get the money back.

Comment: This is useful if true, but goes against an already proposed answer.  Can you please cite a source?

Answer (score -1):

Look up the PSN Terms of Service for your local Playstation Store. There you will find a section "PSN wallet and adding funds" or similar. For me personally, that section says this: "(ix) You must use funds within 24 months of being added to your PSN wallet." For me that implies that the funds may as well just disappear after that time if unused.

Comment: Can you provide a source or link to the PSN Terms of Service for your area to support this?

Comment: This may be country specific, for the US there are no such lines in PSN ToS: https://www.playstation.com/en-us/network/legal/terms-of-service/